# mongo / mongoose aggregation pipeline query for survey data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

I am trying to write a query to get all of the results of some survey data stored in a mongo. The tricky part is some questions are radio questions with a single answer, and some questions are multi-select type questions, some are values that need to be averaged, so I want to perform different aggregations depending on the type of question.

The results are stored in a schema like this, with each item in the array being a survey response.

```
[
  {
    metaData: {
      survey: new ObjectId("62206ea0b31be3535abac547")
    },
    answers: {
      'question1': 'a',
      'question2': 'a',
      'question3': ['a','c'],
      'question4': 3
    },
    createdAt: 2022-03-03T07:30:40.517Z,
  },
  {
    metaData: {
      survey: new ObjectId("62206ea0b31be3535abac547"),
    },
    answers: {
      'question1': 'a',
      'question2': 'b',
      'question3': ['a','c'],
      'question4': 2
    },
    createdAt: 2022-03-03T07:30:40.518Z,
  },
  {
    metaData: {
      survey: new ObjectId("62206ea0b31be3535abac547"),
    },
    answers: {
      'question1': 'b',
      'question2': 'c',
      'question3': ['b']
      'question4': 1
    },
    createdAt: 2022-03-03T07:30:40.518Z,
  }
]
```

question1 and question2 are radio questions, so there can be only 1 answer, whereas question 3 is a multi-select, so the user can have multiple answers. Question 4 is a value that needs to be averaged.

I think there is some way to accomplish this in a single aggregation pipeline with some combination of facets, grouping, filters, projections, etc, but I am stuck.

I'd like to get a final result that looks like this

```
{ 
  'question1' : {
    'a' : 2,
    'b' : 1 
  },
  'question2' : {
    'a' : 1,
    'b' : 1,
    'c' : 1,
  },
  'question3' : {
    'a' : 2,
    'b' : 1,
    'c' : 2,
  },
  'question4' : 2 //avg (3+2+1)/3
}
```

OR even better:

```
{ 
  'radio': {
    'question1' : {
      'a' : 2,
      'b' : 1 
    },
    'question2' : {
      'a' : 1,
      'b' : 1,
      'c' : 1,
     },
  },
  'multi': {
    'question3' : {
      'a' : 2,
      'b' : 1,
      'c' : 2,
    }
  },
  'avg' : {
    'question4' : 2
  }
}
```

My pipeline would look something like this:

```
Response.aggregate([
{ $match: { 'metaData.survey': surveyId} }, // filter only for the specific survey
{ $project: { // I assume I have to turn the answers into an array
  "answers": { $objectToArray: "$answers" },
  "createdAt": "$createdAt"
  }
},
// maybe facet here?
// conceptually, In the next stage I'd want to bucket the questions
// by type with something like below, then perform the right type of
// aggregation depending on the question type
// if $in [$$answers.k  ['question1, 'question2']] group by k, v and count
// if $in [$$answers.k  ['question3']] unwind and count each unique value?
// { $facet : { radio: [], multi:[]}}
])
```

Basically, I know which question Id is a radio or a multi-select, I'm just trying to figure out how to format the pipeline to achieve the desired output based on the questionId being in a known array.

Bonus points if I can figure out how to also group the by day/month based on the createdAt time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $project: { answers: { $objectToArray: "$answers" } }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$answers"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$answers.v"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$answers",
      c: { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.k",
      v: { "$push": { k: "$_id.v", v: "$c" } }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      v: { "$push": { k: "$_id", v: { "$arrayToObject": "$v" } } }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: { v: { $arrayToObject: "$v" } }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$v"
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/quAL6TS3hFk)

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $project: { answers: { $objectToArray: "$answers" } }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$answers"
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "answers.type": {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: { $isArray: "$answers.v" },
              then: "multi"
            },
            {
              case: { $eq: [ { $type: "$answers.v" }, "string" ] },
              then: "radio"
            },
            {
              case: { $isNumber: "$answers.v" },
              then: "avg"
            }
          ],
          default: "other"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$answers.v"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$answers",
      c: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.k",
      type: { $first: "$_id.type" },
      v: {
        $push: {
          k: { $toString: "$_id.v" },
          v: "$c"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$type",
      v: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: { $arrayToObject: "$v" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      v: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: { $arrayToObject: "$v" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: { v: { $arrayToObject: "$v" } }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$v"
  },
  {
    $set: {
      avg: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$avg" },
            as: "s",
            in: {
              k: "$$s.k",
              v: {
                $avg: {
                  $map: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$$s.v" },
                    as: "x",
                    in: { $multiply: [ { $toInt: "$$x.k" }, "$$x.v" ] }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YYbtuI3mHQl)

Comment: Thanks @YuTing, this is eally helpful. I was just wondering, is there a way to specify which questions are handled in which way, like by testing if the key is in an array? We may add other types of questions as well that need to be handled differently, like a 4th question may be numeric and need to be averaged.

Comment: I updated the original question to reflect this with the addition of another type of question that needs an average

Comment: @AlanMayer I update my answer according to your additional question.

Comment: I'm still having trouble figuring out how to do this by date. I asked another question, but maybe you could possibly help one last time? It's basically the same data but asking how to break it down by date and get totals [the new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71354657/mongoose-complex-aggregation-pipeline-question).